# What does the symbol ⌒ mean?

Tags: notation, physics, mathematical-physics

I have come across the following notation when summing over the orthogonal projections of an arbitrary base $n$ in the Hilbert space with $p_{i}, p_j$ being the probability finding the quantum state $\Psi_i, \Psi_j$

[image: Arc notation]

What does this ⌒ symbol mean?

**Edit:**

This is part of the following exercise
[image: density operator]

Comment: Who in their right mind writes like this?

Comment: @Servaes A theoretical physics professor

Comment: I was going to ask whether this was physics; I added the tag. Is the first part supposed to be
$$\sum_n|n\rangle\langle n|=...?$$

Comment: @Servaes yes indeed

Comment: I once had a professor who wrote $\Psi$ like that (the entire thing right of "="). This was also in a physics course (quantum mechanics) and had to do with these sums over bra and ket vectors. So maybe he just called this sum $\Psi$?

Comment: @TMO No her $\Psi$ look different. I can post the whole calculation if this gives better perspective

Comment: Maybe do so, yes.

Comment: The vertical line is part of a double-struck $1$ (), which is one way to to denote the identity operator. I have no idea what the arc afterwards should be, though.

Comment: I have no clue about any of this, but could it be
$$\sum_n|n\rangle\langle n|=\Bbb{}^n$$

Comment: Seeing that on the left of the second equal sign (the one after the arc) is an operator, but on the right there is a scalar expression, maybe the arc belongs to the following apparent equality sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I see the full context, I think I see what's happening:

There's an ongoing calculation, and the second equals sign is part of that ongoing calculation (that is, the thing to its right is equal to the thing on the *previous* line).

Left of it there is the completeness relation
$$\sum_n \lvert n\rangle\langle n\rvert = \large{\unicode{0x1d7d9}}$$
where the double-struck $1$ () denotes the identity operator.

The arc is meant not as a mathematical symbol, but as a connecting line from that relation to the equals sign, to signify that the relation was used to establish that equality.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This not only makes sense, but also seems very clear once you have seen it.

Comment: And I thought I learn new beatiful math, but it may just be confusing handwriting